# Applying FBX file data to 3D camera in blender

Tags: tracking, .fbx

So I did a 3D track in Boujou 5 and exported the FBX file, converted it to another version of FBX file so Blender can read it and now I'm stuck here. Apply the camera data to a 3d camera in blender, I just don't know how to do it.

I have an image of the animated camera from the track, I've highlighted where exactly they are.

[image]

Comment: Is impossible view image due to your privacy setting. Anyway - You need to upload your image here  - so solution can see someone years later. This forum is not designed for "one time purpose".

Comment: I fixed the image :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. activate the "3D view: copy attributes" addon from your User preferences (CTRL+ALT+U)
2. Save user settings.
3. Close window, return to blender 3D view.
4. Space bar > search > import FBX file. Locate your boujou FBX file. Open it.
5. Draw a new space area for window, SHIFT+F9 to make your current view to outliner. Search using filter: CAMERA. If there´s a camera you´re in luck, go to 6.
6. select that camera and press CTRL+ALT+Numpad 0. It will make the camera you selected fro myour outline from bojou the "current" view camera. Press 0 in the numpad, your viewport will switch to camera view. Press ALT+A to play animation. See if it matches.
   // You don´t need to apply any camera data to blender. Your FBX file SHOULD have a camera element. 
   Click on your camera from boujou, and go to camera properties on blender (properties zone to your right side of the screen, the camera icon). From there you should have all the properties Boujou sent, like aspect ratio, lens, sensor, etc.. Should all match accordingly.

Comment: That helps immensely! Thank you! 3d motion tracking has been such a huge issue for me. I still don't have it lined up, i think i just need to get my camera settings correct in either boujou or blender. Things are making a lot more sense though. Thank you! I'll post my results when I figure it out. Cheers!

Comment: awesome. Vote me up on the answer I gave you. Thanks

Comment: That helped a lot but I have a new problem, I asked that question here...https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/111813/fbx-file-boujou-track-data-lags-behind-video

Comment: I´d gladly continue to help you. Just vote up my answer. Thanks.