# FBX file boujou track data lags behind video

Tags: tracking, .fbx

I got my FBX track from boujou in blender but I can't seem to get the track to move with my video, I've checked the frame rate and made sure all settings in boujou match blenders.

The track is always just lagging behind the video and I just can't figure it out. I'm not sure what else it could be.

You can clearly see my problem in my gif.

[image]

Comment: Something like this you can track easily on blender.

Comment: Thats not the full shot though its a much longer shot with more movement and blender just couldn't handle it

Answer (score -1):

Did you pre-cached? 
Also check your current timeline is running at 23.976 it looks like your video is not 24 full frame. Check your video´s fps, then the timeline (render), then the cache before you track.
You need to re-do the track after you set all those things up.
Please vote me up on my answer if you find it useful. Thanks.

Comment: I did everything at 23.976 fps but I know boujou doesn't diffentiate between 23.976 fps and 24fps so I tried both with the same result. But since I shot the footage in 23.976 at 4k I'm going to keep it that way. I've also tried rendering a smaller 1080p version of the video with the same results, it plays faster but it has the same result. So I've also been trying to search how to pre-cache I think i know how but it doensn't seem to work. Are you saying cache before I track in boujou? Or cache the tracking data before I play the camera motion.(See next comment)

Comment: Also everything in the camera in blender plays fine until I play the video as the background. It plays better in 1080p but still lags behind, or the track lags behind. I'm not sure which.

Comment: HOW IN THE WORLD MY ANSWER GOT -1¿? I´ve mentioned correctly this is a caching issue. What´s wrong?

Comment: I didn't down vote, just so you know.